# Wrap searched term without affecting uppercase/lowercase

Tags: php

How do I wrap tags around a search term and keep the original uppercase/lowercase phrase?

So I have this code:

```
$text = 'Hello world';
$search = 'hello';
$text = str_ireplace($search, '<span>' . $search . '</span>', $text);
echo $text;
```

This results with:

```
<span>hello</span> world
```

While I want it to keep original letter case. So:

```
<span>Hello</span> world
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace` which allows back-referencing the string that was found with `$0`:

```
$text = preg_replace("~" . preg_quote($search) . "~i", '<span>$0</span>', $text);
```

Make sure you use a character as regular expression delimiter that does not occur in your search string. I took `~`, but it could be another unusual character.

If you cannot be sure, then escape the chosen character in the search string:

```
$text = preg_replace("~" . str_replace("~", "\\~", preg_quote($search)) . "~i", 
                     '<span>$0</span>', $text);
```

Comment: Lovely! Can I use a double `~~` which would decrease the chance of a user searching with it?

Comment: No, but you can escape the `~` in the search string. See addition to my answer.